# LitElement: keep scroll position during re-render

Tags: javascript, scroll, polymer, lit-element

folks!

I have a dashboard application which consists of a more or less long page. At the end of the page, there's a grid container showing some data. Inside this container, the user can switch between different views of this container, which then changes a `property` (`_activeAlarmsListViewSet`, can be either `list` or `top`).

The switching between the views works fine and as expected, the only thing I encounter is, that the page jumps to the top during the rendering.

I already tried catching the `update()` call and handle it by myself (and yes, no jumping anymore), but also there's no more view switching as no re-render happens:

```
update(changedProperties) {
  if (changedProperties.has('_activeAlarmsListViewSet') && changedProperties.get('_activeAlarmsListViewSet') != null) {
    console.log('No re-render');
  } else {
    super.update(changedProperties);
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility I can trigger the re-rendering without "jumping" to the top of the page and keep the scrolling position?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `shouldUpdate` instead of trying to hack the `update` function.

Comment: are you using `<a>` tag for click to change view? if so., try with `button`

Comment: @vdegenne But that's just another way to trigger the re-rendering, which then causes the jumping.

Comment: @webmonkey the update of a component in the main view shouldn't trigger a bump to the top. There is something wrong in your code that causes that. You should try to understand where the issue comes from before messing with the update functions of this element. Is your code in a public place ? I could help you.

Comment: @vdegenne Damn, I tried to create a similiar thing on Stackblitz  (as the application isn't public, https://stackblitz.com/edit/jumping-rerender?file=my-element.js), but in my demo it does not jump to the top... I now try to understand what's the difference...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is LitElement - when `render` is called only the parts that have changed update, the rest of the DOM remains unchanged and wherever you have scrolled to remains as long as the content is tall enough.

I think the issue is that you have a reflow between the *list* and *top* states that has shorter height, so that the browser corrects the scroll to the intermediate max height.

I most commonly see this with loaders and async directives, as these replace the DOM while waiting for a Promise.

For instance:

```
render() {
    return html`... ${until(getAndRenderData(), 'loading...')}`;
}
```

Will cause the DOM of the loaded data to be replaced with `loading...` *every* time any update happens, while we only want it to happen when `getAndRenderData()` might change.

There are couple of ways around this, but simplest is probable to to use a `guard` directive:

```
render() {
    return html`... ${guard(this._activeAlarmsListViewSet, 
        () => until(getAndRenderData(this._activeAlarmsListViewSet), 'loading...'))}`;
}
```

Now the content in the `guard` only changes when `this._activeAlarmsListViewSet` changes, and you don't have to block the `update` call.

Another way I find works is to split your *list* or *top* views with internally consistent states - Lit doesn't re-render sub-components unless their properties change (in which case they handle it themselves). You can then have these maintain the consistent height as you switch between them.